# AngularStrap Modal Factory - dismiss / confirm prompt functions

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I am making a factory for controlling prompts when users try and delete elements. I am having trouble trying to figure out how either dismiss the action with the close button, or delete if they confirm.

Here is my code in the controller.

```
$scope.removeGateway = function (index) {
  var data = {
    'title': 'Are you sure?',
    'content': 'Deleting this gateway can not be undone.',
  }
  if (NotificationService.prompt(data)) {
    $scope.gatewayItems.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

Here is my factory

```
angular
  .module('App:Admin')
  .factory('NotificationService', function ($modal, $alert) {
    return {
      alert: function (data) {
        $alert(data);
      },
      prompt: function (data) {
        var promptModal = $modal({
          content: data.content,
          title: data.title,
          templateUrl: 'promptModal.html',
          show: false
        });
        promptModal.$promise.then(promptModal.show);
        var confirm = function () {
          promptModal.hide;
          return true;
        }
      },
    }
  });
```

Here is my modal template

```
.modal(tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type='button', ng-click='$hide()') ×
        h4.modal-title(ng-bind="title")
      .modal-body
        p(ng-bind="content")
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button', ng-click='$hide()') Close
        button.btn.btn-danger(type='button', ng-click='confirm()') Delete
```

Comment: Better use callbacks. like prompt: function(data, onOk) { .... var confirm = function() { promptModal.hide; onOk()

Comment: The confirm() function isn't even firing in this example. I think I'm missing something else.

Comment: I'm struggling with this same issue now...did you ever find a solution?